# How can I make a directory in Java?

Tags: java, directory, external-sorting

I am trying to create a new file directory, but the function `mkdir()` doesn't work, neither `mkdirs()`.

Here's my code:

```
...
  while (leitor.hasNext()){
      String [] plv = LerPalavras(tamMem, leitor);
      Arrays.sort(plv);
      String nomeTemp = "/temp/temp" + contador + ".txt"; // I need to create this directory
      try{
        escritor = new FileWriter(nomeTemp);
        for (int i = 0; i < tamMem; i++) {
          escritor.write(plv[i] + " ");
        }
        escritor.close();
      } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      contador++;
    }
...
```

**Edit:** I made the edits and now it's working!

```
File pastaTemp = new File("/temp/temp");
    pastaTemp.mkdirs();

    while (leitor.hasNext()){
      String [] plv = LerPalavras(tamMem, leitor);
      Arrays.sort(plv);
      File arqTemp = new File (pastaTemp, contador + ".txt");
      try{
        escritor = new FileWriter(arqTemp);
        for (int i = 0; i < tamMem; i++) {
          escritor.write(plv[i] + " ");
        }
        escritor.close();
      } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      contador++;
    }
```

Comment: `new File("/temp/temp").mkdirs()` should be able to make the directory structure `temp/temp` at the root dir, assuming it doesn't already exist, so you might to check that first. The other problem is, you may not have permission to create a directory at the root level, something to beware of, might be better creating within the user's home directory context instead

Comment: Not what you asked about, but this is not the correct way to write an external sort. You need to look up replacement selection. It produces sorted runs twice as long as what you're doing, which can save you tons of merge time, entire merge passes in fact.

Comment: @EJP I'm not sure if I understood all that you said, but this is the first look up at the file, after that, I use a quicksort algorithm to sort these files. Anyway, it's just a simple algorithm for a college work, not big deal haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this in two steps.  First, call `File.mkdirs()` to create the entire directory structure, if necessary, then create the file you pass to the `FileWriter`:

```
try {
    File folder = new File("/temp/temp");
    folder.mkdirs();
    // then create a file object at this location
    File file = new File(folder, contador + ".txt");

    escritor = new FileWriter(file);
    // the rest of your code
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: @marianod323 Telling me "it doesn't working" does not let me help you.  I have answered your original question.  Please don't keep updating your question like this, as it may draw downvotes.

Comment: I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Actually, I'm really sorry. It worked, I just didn't realize the path. My bad, again, sorry about that and thank you!